# iOS Wikitude ambigous rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, wikitude

I'm using Wikitude SDK. And loading the architect world from a URL. The SDK load and renders just fine IMAGE[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkHbM.png). When clicked on a link within the architect world a browser opens [which is the required behaviour]. After it opens and I rotate the device and then navigate back to the application the SDK renders incorrectly IMAGE[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0rTS.png) The VK Logo overlaps.

I've tried managing the application life cycle. Stopped the SDK in viewDidDisappear and started it in the viewWillAppear method but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the latest version of the Wikitude SDK (5.1.1). Version 5.0 had an issue related to OpenGL and this was fixed in a later update.

Comment: You are a life saver Sir :) updating to 5.1.1 worked for me.